# How to preserve scroll position on the first page when navigating back from another page in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, local-storage

Let's say I have two pages/two routes. In one I have a `<Link>` component:

```
<Link to="/something">
    <Button>
        This is Link
    </Button>
</Link>
```

In the second, I can go back to the previous route:

```
const handleGoBack = () => {
    navigate(-1);
};

return (

    <Button onClick={handleGoBack}>
        Back
    </Button>
);
```

What is the best way to save the position of the first page to where I clicked that  `<Link>` component, so that when I navigate back from another page, I should return to the exact position I clicked the link from?

I tried adding this to the first component:

```
function storeScrollPosition() {
    sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', window.scrollY.toString());
}
```

And then I use that in the `<Link>` as `onClick` action:

```
<Link to="/something" onClick={storeScrollPosition}>
    <Button>
        This is Link
    </Button>
</Link>
```

, while doing all logic in `useEffect` in the second component:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const scrollPosition = sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPosition');
    if (scrollPosition) {
        window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollPosition));
        sessionStorage.removeItem('scrollPosition');
    } else {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}, []);
```

But it seems that it’s not working perfectly. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn’t work. I don't know, but I think it has something to do with page rendering. Is there by chance any better way to do this?

*I use react-router-dom for navigation.

Comment: What router are you using? If you are using the Data APIs then you can use the [ScrollRestoration](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration) component. If you are not using the Data APIs then please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant routing/navigation code you are working with.

Answer (score -1):

You can preserve the scroll position using react router component i.e., `<ScrollRestoration />`.

Just add the following code to your root route -

```
import { ScrollRestoration } from 'react-router-dom';

export const function RootRoute() {
 return (
  <>
   {/* your code */}
   <ScrollRestoration />
  </>
 );
}
```

Reference: [doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/scroll-restoration)